How to add pulsating and hover effects to a detailed svg in css?
This is a react component in which i have these detailed and beautiful svg.
import "./App.css";
import logo from "./assets/image_1711723636308_ynt4tg.svg";
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="svg-container">
        <svg
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          width="512"
          height="512"
          viewBox="0 0 512 512"
          version="1.1"
        >
          <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0%" y1="100%" x2="0%" y2="0%">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#196A0b" />
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#32de13" />
          </linearGradient>
          <path
            className="svg-path"
            d="M 231 27.122 C 195.135 31.246, 158.690 44.757, 127.500 65.492 C 79.673 97.288, 46.347 145.740, 31.956 204.402 C 13.159 281.019, 34.767 358.611, 90.982 416.360 C 104.694 430.446, 115.257 439.289, 130.524 449.467 C 152.064 463.825, 184.308 477.014, 211.172 482.453 C 228.662 485.994, 227.579 486.238, 228.933 478.462 C 229.559 474.867, 229.804 471.492, 229.477 470.962 C 229.150 470.433, 227.446 469.995, 225.691 469.989 C 220.135 469.971, 199.557 465.352, 187.816 461.488 C 139.325 445.529, 96.795 411.523, 71.436 368.435 C 68.338 363.171, 65.979 358.687, 66.194 358.472 C 66.410 358.257, 70.166 359.232, 74.543 360.638 C 81.221 362.785, 83.758 363.114, 90.327 362.687 C 94.632 362.407, 98.457 361.873, 98.827 361.500 C 99.859 360.458, 94.262 356.407, 89.723 354.909 C 85.380 353.475, 75.958 344.847, 77.994 344.169 C 80.821 343.226, 85.955 337.618, 88.578 332.607 C 91.911 326.242, 91.288 324.693, 84.676 322.913 C 75.747 320.508, 65.866 324.803, 61.092 333.163 C 57.634 339.216, 57.165 338.752, 54.485 326.629 C 51.118 311.394, 54.500 298.527, 63.725 291.483 C 69.493 287.080, 72.940 286.936, 75.341 291 C 77.320 294.350, 79.092 294.765, 81.429 292.429 C 83.918 289.939, 83.324 286.450, 79.923 283.589 C 77.159 281.263, 76.011 281, 68.623 281 C 63.909 281, 59.924 280.524, 59.285 279.885 C 57.914 278.514, 59.234 274.458, 64.362 264.274 C 70.564 251.959, 70.928 243.935, 65.497 239.250 C 60.083 234.580, 51 237.818, 51 244.418 C 51 249.734, 55.052 252.249, 60.750 250.470 C 64.359 249.342, 63.617 252.471, 57.158 265.613 C 51.905 276.303, 47.403 288.208, 45.480 296.500 L 44.785 299.500 43.797 297 C 40.118 287.686, 38.139 259.591, 39.926 242.066 C 44.624 196.008, 61.140 153.588, 87.064 121 C 123.234 75.529, 181.435 44.827, 238.746 40.984 C 300.829 36.820, 358.040 56.768, 402.775 98.175 C 421.298 115.320, 432.977 130.189, 443.269 149.727 C 456.635 175.101, 464.146 197.382, 469.181 226.597 C 472.372 245.110, 472.365 276.960, 469.166 291.431 C 467.959 296.894, 466.786 301.547, 466.560 301.773 C 466.335 301.999, 465.855 300.005, 465.494 297.342 C 464.288 288.447, 461.022 277.993, 456.046 267.101 C 453.334 261.165, 450.816 255.114, 450.449 253.654 C 449.811 251.110, 449.951 251, 453.820 251 C 460.154 251, 462.501 247.388, 459.890 241.657 C 456.933 235.168, 447.728 235.839, 444.432 242.784 C 442.107 247.685, 443.071 253.130, 448.501 265.772 C 453.387 277.143, 453.775 279.112, 451.503 280.997 C 450.346 281.958, 448.992 281.984, 445.523 281.110 C 439.607 279.621, 433.241 281.035, 430.250 284.503 C 427.766 287.383, 427.480 289.161, 429.035 292.066 C 430.532 294.862, 433.163 294.446, 436.253 290.925 C 439.362 287.381, 441.102 287.527, 447.487 291.867 C 456.553 298.029, 460.302 313.486, 456.496 329.015 C 454.566 336.891, 453.625 338.079, 451.932 334.778 C 446.458 324.106, 433.051 319.446, 422.779 324.644 C 420.415 325.841, 420.182 326.349, 421.007 328.518 C 423.171 334.211, 425.491 337.727, 429.700 341.690 L 434.149 345.880 431.824 349.049 C 429.101 352.763, 426.368 354, 420.889 354 C 417.997 354, 416.238 354.671, 414.455 356.455 C 413.105 357.805, 412 359.391, 412 359.979 C 412 363.426, 426.008 363.979, 436.898 360.961 C 440.945 359.840, 444.418 359.085, 444.617 359.283 C 444.815 359.482, 442.276 364.214, 438.974 369.799 C 407.058 423.780, 355.773 458.344, 292.476 468.529 C 287.010 469.409, 282.363 470.304, 282.148 470.519 C 281.933 470.734, 282.073 473.855, 282.458 477.455 C 283.300 485.311, 282.335 485.102, 300.972 481.468 C 333.953 475.037, 365.437 461.743, 391.108 443.409 C 401.221 436.186, 423.951 414.369, 432.687 403.500 C 459.607 370.008, 479.616 325.173, 485.125 286 C 487.139 271.677, 486.669 245.322, 484.092 228.203 C 478.988 194.280, 466.483 159.453, 449.676 132.349 C 413.789 74.476, 347.665 33.786, 278.576 27.063 C 265.976 25.837, 241.916 25.867, 231 27.122 M 251.658 49.548 C 246.951 55.925, 243.085 63.700, 242.341 68.289 C 241.846 71.333, 242.768 74.064, 248.126 85.431 C 255.113 100.251, 256.594 101.528, 259.519 95.250 C 260.480 93.188, 263.265 87.450, 265.707 82.500 C 269.540 74.730, 270.070 72.906, 269.579 69.150 C 268.887 63.851, 263.937 54.313, 258.979 48.727 L 255.313 44.595 251.658 49.548 M 204.169 67.437 C 196.371 69.958, 192.857 74.932, 192.857 83.450 C 192.857 93.162, 197.497 100.360, 206.500 104.617 C 211.948 107.192, 216.311 107.595, 220.685 105.925 C 223.135 104.990, 223.294 104.698, 221.916 103.675 C 221.044 103.029, 220.034 101.304, 219.670 99.843 C 219.306 98.381, 218.733 96.469, 218.397 95.593 C 216.558 90.801, 230.769 98.166, 239.462 106.511 C 244.955 111.784, 250.105 121.206, 253.609 132.393 L 255.455 138.285 256.263 134.393 C 256.708 132.252, 258.900 126.722, 261.135 122.104 C 264.203 115.765, 266.875 112.054, 272.038 106.962 C 279.784 99.323, 290.379 93.240, 292.652 95.126 C 294.714 96.837, 294.275 98.631, 291.250 100.858 C 287.303 103.765, 289.093 106.394, 295.295 106.802 C 304.108 107.383, 314.028 100.965, 317.625 92.355 C 319.812 87.120, 319.397 78.879, 316.750 74.990 C 312.591 68.878, 309.724 67.500, 301.177 67.500 C 290.626 67.500, 284.176 70.588, 274.562 80.243 C 266.054 88.787, 262.447 94.582, 258.888 105.426 L 256.276 113.384 253.982 105.659 C 246.705 81.145, 221.526 61.825, 204.169 67.437 M 153.861 79.912 C 150.557 82.587, 150.468 90.912, 153.708 94.152 C 155.621 96.065, 156.260 96.202, 158.505 95.180 C 164.930 92.252, 165.483 95.095, 161.389 110 C 158.039 122.197, 158.342 131.339, 162.332 138.479 C 163.790 141.087, 164.761 143.578, 164.491 144.015 C 164.221 144.452, 162.312 144.589, 160.250 144.320 C 152.760 143.341, 146.520 148.455, 148.880 153.637 C 149.999 156.091, 150.280 156.164, 156.049 155.494 C 166.656 154.263, 182.505 159.461, 203.669 171.111 C 223.610 182.088, 242.335 204.702, 244.895 220.902 C 246.346 230.079, 245.643 230.634, 239.206 225.390 C 236.139 222.892, 229.434 218.378, 224.308 215.361 C 214.152 209.385, 212 206.721, 212 200.131 C 212 196.675, 212.451 195.884, 215.500 194 C 219.637 191.443, 219.868 189.777, 216.545 186.455 C 212.451 182.360, 208.930 183.447, 207.472 189.256 C 207.030 191.016, 206.117 192, 204.926 192 C 203.904 192, 201.432 192.780, 199.432 193.734 C 195.846 195.444, 195.771 195.436, 193.898 193.123 C 192.854 191.833, 192 189.928, 192 188.889 C 192 187.673, 191.295 187, 190.019 187 C 187.575 187, 186.512 190.588, 187.460 195.641 C 187.985 198.438, 187.839 199.146, 186.820 198.733 C 172.872 193.079, 169.255 192.039, 158.118 190.482 C 138.580 187.751, 132.456 188.826, 105.259 199.762 C 88.078 206.671, 82.524 210.269, 79.630 216.368 C 76.402 223.169, 78.487 228.099, 86.345 232.252 C 89.779 234.068, 92.061 234.435, 99.500 234.371 C 111.368 234.268, 119.253 231.476, 135.228 221.723 C 150.487 212.406, 153.772 210.758, 162.355 208.113 C 171.452 205.309, 183.415 205.297, 194.317 208.081 C 205.531 210.944, 207.201 212.238, 198.500 211.322 C 169.844 208.304, 152.105 216.970, 152.022 234.027 C 151.995 239.640, 154.058 242.733, 158.367 243.541 C 163.854 244.570, 168.140 241.970, 175.380 233.219 C 182.537 224.568, 187 220.817, 187 223.451 C 187 224.680, 188.750 224.946, 196.750 224.933 C 211.847 224.909, 221.594 228.557, 231.332 237.876 C 233.990 240.419, 237.365 244.750, 238.832 247.500 C 241.363 252.244, 241.491 253.166, 241.329 265.500 C 241.225 273.432, 240.343 283.178, 239.067 290.500 C 237.009 302.309, 231.680 323.281, 230.080 325.871 C 229.448 326.893, 228.023 326.372, 223.826 323.585 C 214.316 317.271, 203.224 316.416, 197.148 321.529 C 191.766 326.058, 192.759 334.053, 199.190 337.974 C 203.281 340.469, 211.423 340.658, 218.917 338.432 C 221.821 337.570, 224.490 337.161, 224.849 337.524 C 226.246 338.940, 212.889 349.979, 205.277 353.699 C 197.622 357.440, 197.319 357.499, 186 357.462 C 173.275 357.420, 165.946 355.484, 159.289 350.407 C 149.903 343.248, 152.550 331.435, 163.972 329.505 C 168.471 328.745, 170.250 327.043, 170.250 323.500 C 170.250 317.584, 163.858 315.033, 155.261 317.516 C 136.837 322.836, 131.370 348.908, 145.605 363.555 C 159.209 377.552, 184.090 376.909, 206.323 361.984 C 210.270 359.334, 213.663 357.330, 213.862 357.529 C 214.062 357.729, 213.701 360.076, 213.061 362.745 C 211.318 370.010, 214.091 375.685, 218.555 373.989 C 221.783 372.763, 231.488 363.456, 236.525 356.755 C 239.046 353.401, 242.923 346.909, 245.140 342.329 C 247.357 337.748, 249.555 334, 250.024 334 C 251.359 334, 251.899 340.836, 252.355 363.500 C 252.801 385.679, 252.219 391.145, 248.512 399.554 C 246.134 404.947, 240.542 412.001, 238.646 411.998 C 238.016 411.997, 236.238 409.998, 234.695 407.556 C 231.877 403.095, 223.488 396.581, 221.858 397.588 C 219.796 398.862, 217.983 404.358, 217.375 411.173 C 216.354 422.634, 212.890 427.294, 204.453 428.559 C 188.200 430.997, 182.444 408.288, 197.471 401.014 C 201.123 399.246, 202.879 399, 207.835 399.561 C 213.206 400.169, 213.913 400.031, 214.902 398.184 C 216.880 394.487, 216.236 391.173, 213.237 389.622 C 199.978 382.766, 180.753 391.547, 176.467 406.417 C 171.204 424.674, 184.261 443.005, 202.500 442.968 C 216.433 442.940, 228.072 432.317, 228.377 419.351 C 228.474 415.206, 228.059 413.709, 226.374 412.137 C 223.984 409.907, 224.196 405, 226.682 405 C 229.539 405, 231.906 407.092, 238.262 415.234 C 246.369 425.620, 250.302 431.998, 253.088 439.278 C 254.292 442.425, 255.553 444.985, 255.889 444.967 C 256.225 444.949, 258.402 440.938, 260.728 436.054 C 266.245 424.466, 281.678 405, 285.349 405 C 288.063 405, 288.564 409.771, 286.122 412.370 C 281.613 417.170, 285.010 430.453, 292.328 436.631 C 299.401 442.602, 310.438 444.714, 318.684 441.674 C 329.732 437.601, 337.035 426.976, 336.956 415.090 C 336.876 403.100, 332.711 396.011, 322.854 391.085 C 314.113 386.717, 305.225 386.714, 296 391.075 C 287.698 395, 280.385 400.647, 275.975 406.538 L 272.500 411.179 269.236 407.407 C 264.911 402.408, 261.441 394.869, 260.072 387.500 C 258.807 380.687, 258.687 334.312, 259.932 333.542 C 261.239 332.734, 263.599 336.066, 266.878 343.346 C 270.950 352.387, 277.439 361.339, 284.979 368.320 C 294.748 377.365, 298.674 375.668, 297.754 362.802 C 297.263 355.943, 297.266 355.933, 299.381 357.494 C 311.537 366.466, 319.119 370.048, 331.500 372.668 C 349.775 376.536, 368.192 367.469, 372.557 352.454 C 377.874 334.163, 366.948 317, 349.987 317 C 345.944 317, 344.414 317.495, 342.481 319.428 C 340.358 321.551, 340.186 322.236, 341.110 324.887 C 342.197 328.003, 342.869 328.382, 349.190 329.447 C 356.223 330.631, 360.004 338.507, 356.856 345.417 C 354.289 351.051, 341.651 356.721, 329.500 357.690 C 315.977 358.769, 303.385 354.078, 292.630 343.954 C 289.258 340.781, 286.746 337.934, 287.047 337.629 C 287.347 337.324, 290.047 337.727, 293.047 338.525 C 301.129 340.676, 308.792 340.424, 312.982 337.870 C 317.751 334.963, 318.931 333.145, 318.968 328.651 C 319.019 322.478, 312.960 318, 304.557 318 C 300.149 318, 291.971 321.139, 287.513 324.542 L 282.942 328.031 281.124 323.765 C 274.467 308.143, 270.930 290.879, 270.286 270.863 C 269.763 254.619, 269.810 254.095, 272.285 248.688 C 279.081 233.844, 297.132 223.854, 314.621 225.258 C 321.442 225.805, 322.592 225.433, 323.148 222.500 C 323.472 220.791, 324.322 221.297, 329.016 226 C 332.036 229.025, 336.652 234.069, 339.275 237.209 C 342.869 241.511, 344.905 243.079, 347.539 243.573 C 361.439 246.181, 362.986 227.522, 349.669 217.875 C 347.442 216.262, 342.504 213.996, 338.694 212.839 C 332.772 211.040, 330.083 210.810, 320.134 211.256 C 313.735 211.542, 307.600 212.118, 306.500 212.535 C 305.102 213.066, 304.801 212.973, 305.500 212.227 C 307.842 209.729, 324.368 206, 333.101 206 C 347.121 206, 356.872 209.676, 378.055 222.947 C 390.774 230.915, 398.488 233.833, 409.040 234.668 C 422.797 235.756, 433 230.686, 433 222.761 C 433 218.370, 428.670 211.557, 423.711 208.145 C 414.845 202.045, 387.184 191.868, 374.644 190.092 C 362.320 188.346, 343.788 191.126, 330.639 196.692 L 322.778 200.019 323.438 197.393 C 325.004 191.153, 325.052 189.402, 323.707 187.588 C 322.005 185.292, 319 186.075, 319 188.814 C 319 192.185, 315.725 194.140, 311.272 193.428 C 306.314 192.635, 305.717 192.210, 304.487 188.609 C 303.137 184.656, 299.827 183.562, 296.687 186.032 C 292.712 189.159, 292.683 191.657, 296.589 194.636 C 299.417 196.793, 300 197.888, 300 201.042 C 300 206.321, 296.723 209.848, 286.475 215.601 C 281.811 218.219, 275.520 222.566, 272.497 225.261 L 267 230.160 267 225.237 C 267 214.977, 274.022 201.484, 286.108 188.521 C 293.411 180.687, 302.220 174.616, 317.987 166.551 C 330.779 160.008, 341.361 157, 351.589 157 C 356.863 157, 359.288 156.569, 360.429 155.429 C 362.688 153.170, 362.367 150.276, 359.545 147.455 C 357.481 145.390, 356.131 145, 351.045 145 C 344.873 145, 343.783 144.255, 346.573 141.939 C 349.242 139.725, 351.935 133.404, 352.588 127.824 C 353.056 123.830, 352.542 119.706, 350.533 111.312 C 349.060 105.159, 348 98.859, 348.178 97.312 C 348.473 94.740, 348.811 94.524, 352.153 94.781 C 356.840 95.142, 360 91.567, 360 85.904 C 360 78.093, 350.847 74.999, 345.009 80.837 C 340.802 85.044, 340.286 90.730, 342.878 104.329 C 344.049 110.473, 344.975 118.200, 344.936 121.500 L 344.865 127.500 343.540 122.565 C 342.812 119.851, 341.380 117.020, 340.359 116.273 C 337.622 114.272, 333.781 115.110, 332.128 118.069 C 330.143 121.621, 331.303 125.079, 335.349 127.673 C 341.318 131.501, 340.623 138.328, 333.605 144.796 C 329.924 148.189, 322.310 153, 320.620 153 C 320.368 153, 320.645 151.313, 321.236 149.250 C 322.457 144.993, 322.871 128.545, 321.786 127.455 C 320.781 126.446, 310.727 130.691, 305.983 134.128 C 303.799 135.710, 301.672 136.950, 301.256 136.884 C 299.073 136.536, 297.553 137.371, 293.401 141.198 C 286.593 147.474, 285.716 149.816, 285.600 162.049 L 285.500 172.619 280.173 178.559 C 277.243 181.827, 272.329 188.325, 269.252 193 C 266.175 197.675, 263.253 201.950, 262.758 202.500 C 261.376 204.036, 262.846 198.445, 266.100 189.782 C 270.025 179.337, 270 172.206, 266 160.662 C 259.904 143.068, 262.749 133.678, 277.134 123.909 C 283.520 119.572, 284.467 117.141, 280.777 114.557 C 274.806 110.374, 266.490 115.118, 262 125.268 C 259.494 130.932, 257 143.284, 257 150.029 C 257 155.142, 255.377 157.691, 254.605 153.791 C 254.356 152.531, 253.230 146.634, 252.103 140.686 C 249.700 127.997, 245.862 118.750, 241.799 115.857 C 236.604 112.157, 228.460 113.630, 229.202 118.135 C 229.366 119.131, 232.177 122.097, 235.449 124.726 C 244.043 131.630, 247 137.706, 247 148.458 C 247 154.306, 246.388 158.396, 244.886 162.593 C 241.456 172.176, 241.905 178.789, 246.745 190 C 249.001 195.225, 251.136 200.512, 251.491 201.750 C 252.605 205.644, 250.590 204.204, 247.294 198.750 C 245.549 195.863, 241.056 189.748, 237.311 185.163 C 225.076 170.185, 225.796 171.731, 226.170 161.249 C 226.351 156.161, 226.231 151.999, 225.902 151.999 C 225.573 152, 224.485 150.184, 223.484 147.965 C 221.317 143.159, 215.149 137.312, 211.275 136.391 C 209.749 136.028, 207.825 135.150, 207 134.440 C 205.082 132.788, 192.879 127.002, 191.311 127.001 C 188.628 126.999, 188.378 146.101, 190.997 150.994 C 192.345 153.513, 191.908 153.500, 186.710 150.867 C 180.209 147.573, 175.118 143.151, 172.962 138.926 C 170.124 133.362, 170.481 131.320, 175 127.263 C 179.390 123.322, 180.117 120.039, 177.443 116.223 C 175.767 113.829, 172.134 113.323, 168.934 115.035 C 166.540 116.317, 166.485 115.163, 168.500 106 C 170.365 97.520, 170.401 86.676, 168.575 83.145 C 165.956 78.080, 158.222 76.380, 153.861 79.912 M 120.500 101.155 C 117.083 103.024, 116 105.206, 116 110.223 C 116 116.085, 117.719 120.472, 121.868 125.196 C 126.202 130.133, 133.032 132.780, 144.649 134.023 C 150.067 134.603, 155.063 135.271, 155.750 135.507 C 157.770 136.202, 157.200 134.152, 154.130 129.680 C 152.552 127.381, 149.220 121.450, 146.727 116.500 C 141.983 107.082, 138.405 102.847, 133.685 101.064 C 130.072 99.698, 123.074 99.747, 120.500 101.155 M 377.481 101.394 C 372.959 103.364, 368.594 108.937, 364.155 118.410 C 361.966 123.082, 359.010 128.431, 357.587 130.297 C 356.164 132.162, 355 134.122, 355 134.650 C 355 135.599, 361.317 135.059, 374.443 132.988 C 386.849 131.030, 395.061 122.410, 395.816 110.551 C 396.187 104.720, 396.034 104.172, 393.472 102.156 C 390.269 99.638, 382.376 99.261, 377.481 101.394 M 231.501 135.130 C 223.020 137.478, 224.576 149.200, 233.369 149.200 C 238.315 149.200, 242 145.890, 242 141.448 C 242 136.593, 237.027 133.600, 231.501 135.130 M 271.500 135.195 C 267.143 137.666, 266.776 142.391, 270.589 146.923 C 274.413 151.468, 281.481 150.628, 283.890 145.343 C 285.585 141.622, 285.258 140.104, 282.077 136.923 C 278.961 133.807, 275.069 133.171, 271.500 135.195 M 128.500 142.028 C 121.330 144.225, 116 152.641, 116 161.764 C 116 173.002, 123.108 182.173, 134.424 185.533 C 141.569 187.655, 142.542 187.450, 147.510 182.775 C 151.246 179.259, 152 177.934, 152 174.882 C 152 172.616, 151.451 171.003, 150.564 170.663 C 148.707 169.950, 144.002 173.645, 143.993 175.823 C 143.989 176.964, 143.336 176.541, 141.949 174.500 C 140.474 172.329, 140.056 170.517, 140.436 167.945 C 140.786 165.576, 140.423 163.622, 139.349 162.088 C 137.985 160.141, 137.152 159.880, 133.940 160.394 C 129.997 161.024, 126.492 159.045, 127.282 156.634 C 127.922 154.683, 133.268 154.646, 134.684 156.582 C 137.176 159.990, 143 154.996, 143 149.451 C 143 147.002, 137.634 142.015, 134.500 141.552 C 132.850 141.308, 130.150 141.522, 128.500 142.028 M 375.295 142.087 C 369.212 143.884, 367.148 150.376, 371.073 155.365 C 373.567 158.536, 374.273 158.597, 377.845 155.956 C 381.161 153.505, 384.250 154.241, 383.803 157.377 C 383.543 159.200, 382.817 159.505, 378.664 159.539 C 372.869 159.585, 370.057 162.379, 370.022 168.128 C 369.995 172.521, 367.366 175.406, 365.854 172.703 C 364.567 170.404, 360.037 170.440, 359.885 172.750 C 359.596 177.140, 360.401 178.776, 364.797 182.729 C 369.818 187.244, 372.283 187.822, 378.101 185.845 C 386.444 183.010, 392.377 176.515, 394.671 167.709 C 398.481 153.078, 387.454 138.495, 375.295 142.087 M 90.635 151.073 C 85.134 155.400, 88.832 165, 96 165 C 103.168 165, 106.866 155.400, 101.365 151.073 C 99.916 149.933, 97.502 149, 96 149 C 94.498 149, 92.084 149.933, 90.635 151.073 M 409.635 151.073 C 403.996 155.508, 407.844 165, 415.280 165 C 422.470 165, 425.951 155.466, 420.365 151.073 C 418.916 149.933, 416.502 149, 415 149 C 413.498 149, 411.084 149.933, 409.635 151.073 M 69 176.592 C 63.216 179.093, 59 183.847, 59 187.868 C 59 194.549, 69.722 202, 79.337 202 C 83.727 202, 94.570 198.094, 98.910 194.950 L 103.150 191.878 101.400 189.189 C 98.999 185.500, 97.104 184.224, 92.959 183.507 C 90.264 183.041, 89.379 182.379, 89.255 180.737 C 89.166 179.550, 88.059 177.783, 86.796 176.811 C 83.885 174.572, 73.955 174.449, 69 176.592 M 425.554 177.136 C 423.781 178.531, 423.007 179.919, 423.325 181.136 C 423.678 182.483, 423.273 183, 421.867 183 C 419.242 183, 412.944 186.296, 410.586 188.904 C 408.693 190.996, 408.699 191.050, 411.030 193.532 C 414.494 197.219, 422.997 201.042, 429.133 201.670 C 437.216 202.498, 442.685 200.601, 448.248 195.037 C 454.320 188.966, 454.509 186.126, 449.181 181.058 C 442.714 174.905, 430.886 172.942, 425.554 177.136 M 166.625 179.517 C 164.394 181.749, 164.585 186.585, 167 189 C 170.326 192.326, 174.217 191.415, 176.632 186.745 C 178.081 183.944, 178.053 183.548, 176.246 181.116 C 173.901 177.960, 168.998 177.145, 166.625 179.517 M 335 180 C 333.900 181.100, 333 182.935, 333 184.077 C 333 186.860, 338.577 192.376, 340.604 191.599 C 341.462 191.269, 342.565 191, 343.056 191 C 344.166 191, 347 185.647, 347 183.550 C 347 181, 343.216 178, 340 178 C 338.333 178, 336.111 178.889, 335 180 M 402 193.059 C 402 193.641, 402.450 193.840, 403 193.500 C 403.550 193.160, 404 192.684, 404 192.441 C 404 192.198, 403.550 192, 403 192 C 402.450 192, 402 192.477, 402 193.059 M 108.500 194 C 108.160 194.550, 108.332 195, 108.882 195 C 109.432 195, 110.160 194.550, 110.500 194 C 110.840 193.450, 110.668 193, 110.118 193 C 109.568 193, 108.840 193.450, 108.500 194 M 292.071 296.746 C 284.236 300.754, 282.065 309.327, 287.460 314.958 C 290.848 318.494, 293.259 318.749, 297.701 316.040 C 301.731 313.584, 304 309.264, 304 304.050 C 304 300.173, 301.450 296, 299.082 296 C 298.577 296, 297.564 295.773, 296.832 295.496 C 296.099 295.219, 293.957 295.781, 292.071 296.746 M 210.455 298.455 C 207.805 301.104, 207.381 304.235, 209.067 308.685 C 211.331 314.662, 218.493 319.877, 221.920 318.043 C 224.305 316.766, 228 310.886, 228 308.366 C 228 305.014, 224.445 299.708, 220.938 297.827 C 216.326 295.353, 213.379 295.530, 210.455 298.455 M 184.223 342.557 C 177.758 347.084, 186.995 357.473, 195.649 355.408 C 200.940 354.146, 204 351.764, 204 348.907 C 204 345.541, 202.800 344.587, 196.068 342.602 C 189.280 340.600, 187.029 340.591, 184.223 342.557 M 313.819 343.531 C 308.364 346.371, 307.636 347.276, 308.532 350.100 C 309.366 352.729, 314.703 355, 320.045 355 C 323.253 355, 324.795 354.359, 327.077 352.077 C 330.496 348.657, 330.788 345.788, 328 343 C 325.275 340.275, 319.668 340.485, 313.819 343.531 M 298.077 402.589 C 295.143 405.058, 295 405.527, 295 412.707 C 295 420.091, 295.073 420.308, 298.799 424.035 C 303.439 428.674, 308.561 429.942, 314.420 427.899 C 325.729 423.958, 325.884 406.969, 314.660 401.643 C 309.196 399.050, 301.780 399.473, 298.077 402.589"
            stroke="none"
            fill="#296e01"
          />
        </svg>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;


This was my attempt at creating a color filling effect but to no avail.
/* SVGComponent.css */
.svg-container {
    
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.svg-path {
    fill: url(#gradient);
    transition: fill 0.3s ease;
}

/* Animate the gradient */
@keyframes gradientAnimation {
    0% {
        stop-color: #196A0b;
    }
    100% {
        stop-color: #32de13;
    }
}

.svg-container:hover .svg-path {
    animation: gradientAnimation 0.5s ease forwards;
}


I want pulsating and a hover effect in which maybe the fill color of my svg changes from bottom up.

Instead of using css to animate an attribute of the  element you may try to use SMIL animation like in this example: https://codepen.io/NickNoordijk/pen/VLvxLE
